# When creating a VM, memory keeps filling up, and never finishes installation

Tags: storage, virtualbox, oracle

I'm using **VirtualBox** to get started with **Oracle Database**. I downloaded **Database App Development VM** and tried to import it into VB, but every time I try, it stops with the error [0x80070057].

I read online that the reason may be storage-related, so I started emptying out folders (Or moving some to D:). I've emptied over 15 GBs now (On my C:), then tried to import the appliance again, but it didn't work, and somehow **the 15 GBs appear occupied again**.

Every time I delete files and start again, the space gets occupied but the appliance is not installed. I don't really know how to google this. I think it's cache related. I can't delete what's trying (unsuccessfully) to get imported (But still occupying memory).

Could anyone explain what's happening here? How do I empty that space? How do I know the required space for this import after installation (So I don't start again until I have that much)?

Comment: When you delete a file that's in use by another application, it doesn't really go away until the other application closes it. Probably not helpful, but at least educational :)

Comment: Have you consider to use disk D for this VM storage?

Comment: @BarryCarter Tried this, to check if it's still running, but nope. Was a good idea nontheless.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Yeah, I imported everything to D: and it didn't work.